# Transpose not currently implemented for JuMPArrays with arbitrary index sets

Tags: julia-jump

Looks like I can't use the transpose of a vector/matrix in the objective of my goal-seeking code in JuMP.  I get the error stated in the title of this question.  Can anyone suggest a way around this?

Code:

```
using JuMP, ECOS

Supertech = [-.2, .1, .3, .5];
Slowpoke = [.05, .2, -.12, .09];
A = reshape([vec(Supertech); vec(Slowpoke)],length(Slowpoke),2)
mlen = size(A)[1]
R = vec(mean(A,1))
n=rank(A)
λ = .100
items  = [λ; 1-λ]

m = Model(solver=ECOSSolver())
@variable(m, 0 <= take[items] <= 1)  # Define a variable for each item
sharpe_ratio = vec(sqrt(mlen) * (take' * R) / sqrt(sum(vec(take' .* take) .* vec(cov(A,1,false)))))[1]
@objective(m, Max, sharpe_ratio)
@constraint(m, sum(take) == 1)
solve(m)
println(getvalue(take))
```